# No has_key() method for Python 3 dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read "Python Cookbook" and see what in a recipe "Finding the Intersection of Two Dictionaries" authors recommend using such one-liner:

```
filter(another_dict.has_key, some_dict.keys())
```

But since Python 3 dictionaries don't have has_key() method how should I modify suggested code? I suppose there could be some internal __ in__() method or something like this.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 3 has dictionary key views instead, a much more powerful concept.  Your code can be written as

```
some_dict.keys() & another_dict.keys()
```

in Python 3.x.  This returns the common keys of the two dictionaries as a set.

This is also available in Python 2.7, using the method `dict.viewkeys()`.

As a closer match of the original code, you could also use a list comprehension:

```
[key for key in some_dict if key in another_dict]
```

An even closer match of original code would be to use `dict.__contains__()`, which is the magic method corresponding to the `in` operator:

```
filter(another_dict.__contains__, some_dict.keys())
```

But please, don't use this code.  I recommend going with the first version, which is the only one highlighting the symmetry between `some_dict` and `another_dict`.

Comment: What is the difference between `some_dict.keys() & another_dict.keys()` and `another_dict.keys() & some_dict.keys()` ?

Comment: None. The intersection operation is commutative.

Comment: There is one minor difference between `a.keys() & b.keys()` and `b.keys() & a.keys()` -- the performance is better in CPython 3.2 if the shorter one comes first (at least for me, for sufficiently large arrays, today.)  Purely an implementation detail, though.